# Get URL for SockJS client via window.location object

Tags: javascript, sockjs

Speaks anything against `location.origin` in this context?

```
new SockJS(window.location.origin + ':1337/websockets');
```

My websockets are running on the same URL as my web server runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want another port and the definition of `window.location.origin` is

> Returns the protocol, hostname and port number of a URL

you should do like this to make sure you only get the protocol and the hostname

```
new SockJS(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':1337/websockets');
```

Comment: Will port 80 be ignored? In my case origin looks like `http://172.17.22.24` and port is an empty string.

Comment: As you want another port and the definition of `window.location.origin` is "Returns the protocol, hostname and port number of a URL", you should use the above to make sure you only get the protocol and the hostname.

Comment: If not set, usually the port is 80 for web request, and in your case it works using `location.origin`, but by definition this is wrong when you want another port and should use a proper way to get it, not by a "in this case working way" as that can cause you trouble later on.

Comment: Alright. Small notice. `window.location.protocol` returns `http:` so there is no need for adding the `:`.

Comment: My mistake, missed that ... will update answer right away ... done!